# Unix Quotations inside quotations

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Is there a syntax error where the $DATE variable is written inside the if statement?

I am having trouble with quotations inside quotations, here is the code

```
if [ \( ! -f "$CMD_FILE" \) -a \( $CMD_FILE == "myData"$DATE"D_1.zip" \) -a \( $TODAY == "Sat" \); then
touch /home/me/files myData"$DATE"_1.txt
```

Comment: To use compound conditions, you don't need to put each condition inside `()`, I see `if` but no `fi`, I see `[` but no `]`

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:

```
if [ ! -f $CMD_FILE ] && \
[ $CMD_FILE == "myData"$DATE"D_1.zip" ] && \
[ $TODAY == "Sat" ]; then
    echo "yes";
fi
```

If all 3 statements are true the script yields "yes"